# How to fix ng-submit in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am new to NodeJS and I'm  trying to build a forum app using Angular with the ability to reply to comments. I'm able to add comments to a post. But I'm not able add replies to the comments of a post. I think I'm doing something wrong with my controllers and routes.

Basically, I've tried implementing the **reply** function by looking at how the **comment** function was implemented for **posts** i.e. replaced post with comment and comment with reply.

My index.ejs, here I'm able to add comments to the post.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">

..............

<div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
  <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    {{comment.body}}
  </span>
</div>

<form ng-submit="addComment()" id= "my-form" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>Add a new comment</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
</script>
```

To implement the reply functionality, I added the following code

```
<div ng-repeat="reply in comment.replies">
      <span style="font-size:10px; margin-left:10px;">
        {{reply.replytext}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="addReply()" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <h3>Add a new reply</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Reply" ng-model="replytext"></input> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Reply</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

before

```
<form ng-submit="addComment()" id= "my-form" style="margin-top:30px;">
```

in my index.ejs. When I do this, clicking on the reply button does nothing.

The following is what is present in my appAngular.js

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    // .......

    o.addComment = function (id, comment) {
        return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments', comment);
    };

    // .........

    return o;
}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'posts', 'post',
    function ($scope, posts, post) {
        $scope.post = post;
        $scope.addComment = function () {
            if (!$scope.body || $scope.body === '') { return; }
            posts.addComment(post._id, {
                body: $scope.body,
                author: 'user',
            }).success(function (comment) {
                $scope.post.comments.push(comment);
            });
            $scope.body = '';
        };

        // .......

    }]);
```

I wrote the code for o.addReply() similar to o.addComment() which I think is incorrect.

The following is my routes.js,

```
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function (req, res, next) {
    var comment = new Comment(req.body);
    comment.post = req.post;

    comment.save(function (err, comment) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        req.post.comments.push(comment);
        req.post.save(function (err, post) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            res.json(comment);
        });
    });
});

router.param('comment', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Comment.findById(id);

    query.exec(function (err, comment) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!comment) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

        req.comment = comment;
        return next();
    });
});
```

For implementing replies, I added the following to my routes.js

```
router.post('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/replies', function (req, res, next) {
    var comment = new Comment(req.body);
    comment.post = req.post;

    var reply = new Reply(req.body);
    reply.comment = req.comment;

    reply.save(function (err, reply) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        req.post.comments.comment.replies.push(reply);
        req.post.comments.coment.save(function (err, comment) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }

            res.json(reply);
        });
    });
});

router.param('reply', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query1 = Reply.findById(id);

    query1.exec(function (err, reply) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!reply) { return next(new Error('can\'t find comment')); }

        req.reply = reply;
        return next();
    });
});
```

Finally, this is my mongoose model

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: String,
    upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
    reply: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reply' }
});

    .........

var ReplySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    comment: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' },
    replytext: String
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
mongoose.model('Reply', ReplySchema);
```

Comment: you havent pass any param to addComment " ng-submit="addComment()""

Comment: addComment() works. addReply() does not.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of code in your appAngular.js file

```
return $http.post('/posts/' + post._id + '/comments/' + comment._id ++ '/replies', reply);
```

There is a double **+** sign in your route address. It can be source of your problem.

Comment: Check your CommentsCtrl. It seems you didnt connect to it to the view?

Comment: I haven't connected PostCtrl either but addComment() works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="/method2"  method="post" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <h3>Add a new reply</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Reply" ng-model="replytext"></input>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="accept" class="btn btn-secondary">Reply </button>
    </form>
</div>

<form action="/method1"  method="post" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>Add a new comment</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```